# Using symbol "{" in big size

Tags: symbols, scaling

I want to use to symbol `{` in big size and I tested `$\left\{$` but it is not functional. So, I need to help for writing this symbol.

Comment: Did you try `\left\{` along with a matching `\right\}` or `\right.`?  If that does not solve your problem, it would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\left` needs an accompanying `\right` (within the same group) in order for it to work as expected. The null delimiter `.` could be used to provide an accompaniment that shouldn't be printed (and may require some spacing correction).

For fixed-height sizes, you can use `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` or `\Bigg`. Extensible delimiters require `\left` (or [`\mleft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mleftright)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}
\begin{document}

Fixed-height \verb|{|:
\[
  \big\{ \quad \Big\{ \quad \bigg\{ \quad \Bigg\{
\]

Extensible \verb|{|:
\[
  \mleft\{
  \rule{0pt}{5\baselineskip}% Strut, or whatever
  \mright.
\]

\end{document}
```

Typically `\big`-related scaling is used in a `\bigl`-`\bigr` context rather than just `\big` (for spacing purposes).

Answer (score 1):

If you need the curly braces to stay "curvy" even if they're quite large, you may want to look into using the [mtpro2](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) package and its `\LEFTRIGHT` macro. The smallest curly brace, on the left, is generated by `\{`; the largest curly brace is more than 5 cm tall! Note that all braces are "curvy", which is not the case if one uses `\left\{...` to generate them.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
   $\{ 
    \Bigg\{
    \LEFTRIGHT\{.{\vphantom{\xl\sum}}
    \LEFTRIGHT\{.{\vphantom{\XL\sum}}
    \LEFTRIGHT\{.{\vphantom{\XXL\sum}} 
    \LEFTRIGHT\{.{\vphantom{\XXXL\sum}} $
\end{document}
```