# Bigger matching brackets in every level

Tags: brackets

I have the following formula:

[image]

Is there an elegant way to make the matching brackets of one level a little bigger than the matching brackets of the previous one?

Normal -> () -> Bigger -> [] Bigger -> {}

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\setmainfont
[
    Ligatures=TeX,
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*,
    BoldFont=*Bold,
    ItalicFont=*It,
    BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
    Mapping=tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{latinmodern-math.otf}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Formula:
%
\Eqs
{
  y_{n+1}=y_{n}+\frac{h}{2}\{f(x_{n},y_{n})+f[x_{n}+h,y_{n}+hf(x_{n},y_{n})]\}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [Using symbol “{” in big size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244855/5764)

Comment: @Werner I know that way that is why I asked about an elegant one. Maybe something that may perform the resizing at both brackets, like a command from a package that provides more options. Thank you for your comment though. :)

Comment: @PeterGrill -- Stephans solution uses `\left`-`\right`-paired delimiters. I guess for that reason the mentioned solution won't work with the equation given in the example here. I have something in mind, but I dont know if it can be regarded as elegant, as the OP requested...

Comment: Oh, reaching for the stars... the solution *has* to be *elegant*, *easy to use* and *completely automated*... *for free*...

Comment: @Werner Anyone is beginning from the stars and then sees which aspects of his expectations really exist. :P